# Long delay between platform event publish and platform event subscriber processing

Tags: trigger, platform-event, performance, subscriber, automated-process

Kindly help me with following scenario.

In short - need help to minimize the delay between platform event publish and platform event subscriber processing.

Platform Event Details -

- Event Type   - High Volume
- Publish Behavior - Publish After Commit

Platform Event Subscriber Config

- batch Size - 20

Platform Event Subscriber

- Platform Event Trigger
- As per implementation done in "Platform Event Trigger",
- We are processing patform events in bulk.
- we are checking the per transaction governer limits like SOQL Limit, DML Limit are reached or not.
- When per transaction governer limits are about to be fulfilled - We are setting "Resume Check point" and breaking the bulk processing loop.
- As per our analysis - it can process upto 8
  records per transaction.

We have a platform event in our org. as per details mentioned above and we have trigger as subscriber where processing happens.

- As per our analysis and understanding -
- Around 10000 Platform events are published per day.
- At the start of the day - when end user starts using the org. - the delay between platform event publish and platform event subscriber processing is minimal like 4 / 5 mins.
- But as the volume of the user and their activity increases as the day proceeds - the delay between platform event publish and platform
  event subscriber processing increases to 20 / 30 mins , 1 / 2 hours and it reaches to upto 6 / 7 hours at the end of the day.
- Also we tried creating 2 different platform events to acheive the same by distributing platform event publish load evenly. Even after this there is still delay of 4 / 5 hours

Kindly help me with the solution / design to minimize the deplay between publish and subscribe.

Comment: I doubt there is anything you can do about this since it is most likely the way Salesforce handles multi-tenanting and avoids a given org hogging all CPU and other resources. I am guessing you have relatively high CPU needs in processing these events (and hence the low batch size numbers). Is this happening on a production org? Remember that non-production orgs always get worse performance.

Comment: @PhilW  Thanks for your inputs. Yes, We are using it for Heavy Processing and also all of the analysis is as per the Production org.